# Indexing PDF file by SOLR

Tags: pdf, solr

I'm using Solrj to index PDF files whith SOLR, but some files can't index and make an exception

```
GRAVE: Error: Could not parse predefined CMAP file for 'Adobe-Identity-UCS'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMap.lookup(II)Ljava/lang/String;
```

can you tell me what's the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems some mismatch with the apache fontbox jars, which mentions the method not found.
Can you confirm the jars for tika and all its dependencies are in sync and are the ones with the build.
you can also check standalone if the parsing of documents work fine using the Apache Tika project jars.